# Best practice for using location names as part of taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm setting up my taxonomy vocabularies for describing my node content. Most of it's fairly straight-forward, but I'm stuck on how to describe the location data for my nodes.

I have a small hierarchy of place names for a limited geographic region that my site covers. Should I continue to use taxonomy to create a vocabulary, or should I be using the location module? I will be having location-specific content in the node, such as a Google Map to show the location of venues etc. Can location module content be tied up to a taxonomy vocabulary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends of your goal:

- If you want to cover large areas like cities, it's better to use Taxonomy as it will be easier to build (for example) a view (or map) of all node from this city.
- If you want very precise geolocation (like the position of a store in a map), then go for location. Regarding Location module, it may be overkill for simple Lat./Long. positioning and a simple CCK field for each should be enough.
- You can of course have both Taxonomy and Lat./Long. for your nodes and use the one appropriates regarding your context.

If you have time, I'll recommend the listening of [Acquia Podcast 22: DevSeed On Mapping in Drupal](http://acquia.com/resources/podcasts/acquia-podcast-22-devseed-mapping-drupal).

> Being able to display maps in Drupal is a powerful feature, and can
>   also be confusing to implement. Join us as we talk with Ian Cairns,
>   Tom MacWright, and Robert Soden from Development Seed about how it is
>   done and the different options available for displaying great maps.

Comment: Thanks - by the sound of your explanation, I think I should be using both Taxonomy and Location as I want to i) display a view of nodes relating to a particular place, but I also want to be able to display location data in those nodes (like maps and perhaps other location-related information).

I'll check out the podcast, too, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right way'd be to create location terms and while saving the node, the location address fields should copy from the taxonomy term. Using taxonomy terms help your site keep organized.

For example create term name for Delhi as Delh i but have "City Name" from Location input copy it from the taxonomy current taxonomy term Delhi.

How to handle it technically is what I've asked here: [Autopopulate "Postal Code" from taxonomy in Location module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/autopopulate-postal-code-from-taxonomy-in-location-module)