# Autopopulate "Postal Code" from taxonomy in Location module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, location

In Location module input I want to disable "Postal Code" field but the node will have a mandatory vocabulary selection (vocabulary name: Postal Code).

What I want is that when I create a node with the postal code term selection it should automatically populate the "Postal Code" field of location module input from this term.

What is the right way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/12075/2916 ?

Comment: It isn't related in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is with a custom module.

You would implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to disable (or hide altogether) the location postal code on the node form.

You would then implement `presave` op of [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (drupal 6) or [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) (drupal 7) to fill in the location data.

If you don't know PHP, you could also add some custom javascript that changes the location postal code when the taxonomy drop down is changed.

Comment: We can hide a location field in location settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the prepopulate module. My method was to use views to create a url for node creation on my taxonomy pages. Users select the city term and on the page click on "Add a post" link and the form is prepopulated with term from the url.